# mysql check constrain definition

Tags: mysql

I have two fields in a table that are related one to the other.
Say that fieldA can get the value from 1 to 5. Field B can get a value from 1 to 3.
I am currently checking the constrains between them in the application but would like to move it to the db since now Mysql supports `CHECK`constrains.
So I need help to write the constrains for my specific situation.

- if fieldA is 1 then fieldB must be 0
- if fieldA is 2 then fieldB moves to 1 and can go up to 3
- if fieldA is 3 then fieldB must be 0
- fieldA can be 4 only if fiedlB is 3
- fieldA can be 5 only if fieldB is 3

I read [this document](https://dev.mysql.com/blog-archive/mysql-8-0-16-introducing-check-constraint/) to learn how the check constrain works but need some help on understanding if this is really what I need for my solution and how to implement it

Answer (score 1):

Try this out:

```
CREATE TABLE `test_data` (
  `id` BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `fieldA` INT NOT NULL,
  `fieldB` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `chk` CHECK ((((`fieldA` = 1) OR (`fieldA` = 3)) AND (`fieldB` = 0)) OR ((`fieldA` = 2) AND (`fieldB` BETWEEN 1 AND 3)) OR (((`fieldA` = 4) OR (`fieldA` = 5)) AND (`fieldB` = 3)))
)
```

Upon every INSERT/UPDATE, it will execute the condition mentioned in the check-constraint.  And it will not let that INSERT/UPDATE go forward (raise an error) if the check-constraint evaluates to FALSE.

You can have multiple check-constraints too.
All the check-constraints have to be evaluated to TRUE to succeed.

In your case, since all those 5 criteria are in OR, I have combined a few obvious ones and have written 3 conditions in OR.

So, essentially, if we format the check-constraint, it is like this:

```
(
    (((`fieldA` = 1) OR (`fieldA` = 3)) AND (`fieldB` = 0))
    OR
    ((`fieldA` = 2) AND (`fieldB` BETWEEN 1 AND 3))
    OR
    (((`fieldA` = 4) OR (`fieldA` = 5)) AND (`fieldB` = 3))
)
```

Comment: @Lelio, you can create this table, and give it a shot with some INSERT queries, with and without correct data

Comment: will this work also with update?

Comment: Yes, it will work with UPDATE too.  I tried.